# Zooming graph keeping xaxis interval's pixel length constatnt varying their value

Tags: c#, charts, zooming

I want that when i zoom into or out of the graph, the position of the x axis intervals should not change, however their value should change according to the zoom level. I used following code:

public void zoomer(double zoom)

```
    {
            if (zoom < 0)
            {
                zoomFactor += 10;
                chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.ScaleView.Zoom(0, size * zoomFactor);
                //chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Interval = /*(stableTime / 10) + */(zoomFactor * stableTime / 10);
            }
            else if (zoom  > 0)
            {
                zoomFactor -= 10;
                chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.ScaleView.Zoom(0, size * zoomFactor);
                //chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Interval = /*(stableTime / 10) - */(zoomFactor * stableTime / 10);
            }
    }
```

I am a noob and started c# programming just a week back; this code was given to me for refinement. So pleaze give a detailed solution. (I dont even know how ScaleView.Zoom() works; any insight would be a big help)

Thanks.

Comment: this code does not contain something about the x axis grid... can you add more code, what type is stabletime for example. is it a float, a int. And where did you get the examples from?

Comment: the x axis represents time and is of type double and following are the properties of the axes

{
            chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.ScaleView.Zoomable = true;
            chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.ScaleView.SizeType = DateTimeIntervalType.Number;

            chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.ScrollBar.Enabled = true;
            chart1.ChartAreas[0].CursorX.AutoScroll = true;
}

Comment: Sorry I cant figure out why the code seem so messed up.

Comment: There have to be more settings. Can you post the code of the graph class in your question?

Comment: wasn't able to put the whole code there, I have asked the same question again at 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14498051/zooming-graph-keeping-xaxis-intervals-at-fixed-pixel-length-but-varying-their-va